# Object values displayed as hieroglyphs in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am just copied below code from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#i468598)

```
CREATE TYPE phone_typ AS OBJECT (
    country_code   VARCHAR2(2), 
    area_code      VARCHAR2(3),
    ph_number      VARCHAR2(7));
/
CREATE TYPE phone_varray_typ AS VARRAY(5) OF phone_typ;
/
CREATE TABLE dept_phone_list (
  dept_no NUMBER(5), 
  phone_list phone_varray_typ);

INSERT INTO dept_phone_list VALUES (
   100,
   phone_varray_typ( phone_typ ('01', '650', '5550123'),
                      phone_typ ('01', '650', '5550148'),
                      phone_typ ('01', '650', '5550192')));
```

I am run this in SQL DEVELOPER an after creating types and tables, when I see table `dept_phone_list`, this is displayed (please see screenshot)

What is reason of this?

[image]

Comment: Looks OK to me, in version 4. Maybe you have a character set discrepancy between the client and server/session? Also, it's not a good idea to create your own tables in the `SYSTEM` schema.

Comment: Thank you, I was different encoding on server and client, now displayed normally